# DATE CONVERSION IN SQL DEVELOPER RETURNS AN ERROR

Tags: sql, string, oracle, sqlplus

I have this code:

```
DEFINE value1 = '20-JUL-20';

SELECT to_DATE(&&value1, 'DD-MON-YY') from dual;
```

But returns this error:

```
ORA-00904: "JUL": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 17 Column: 19
```

It seems it is having problem converting the string to date.
I am wondering if you guys can explain why and if there is a fix to it.
Thanks.

Comment: You should also specify the language, i. E. add parameter `'nls_date_language=english'`

Comment: Aside from your immediate problem, have you ever heard of something called the Y2k bug?  NEVER USE 2-DIGIT YEARS!

Comment: In my experience, it's much better to **not** rely on language dependent date formats (or two digit years). Using the ISO format `yyyy-mm-dd` will save you a lot of trouble in the long run.

Answer (score 3):

You need single quotes around the substitution variable:

```
DEFINE value1 = '20-JUL-20';
SELECT to_DATE('&&value1', 'DD-MON-YY') from dual;
```